# Cheerio not loading HTML inside Axios get request - all of which is inside an aysnchronous intent handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on an intent for an Alexa skill that is going to get headlines from a news website. My code is in node js and is hosted on AWS Lambda.
I am using axios and cheerio for the web scraping and when I run those on my local machine from the commandline, the code successfully retrieves the HTML and cheerio is able to get the data I need.
However when I run the code on the Lambda, it throws an error every time I try to load the HTML with cheerio.

Interestingly I tried loading an "html string" with cheerio like this:

```
const $ = cheerio.load('<h2 class="title">Hello world</h2>');
```

and I was able to use it and get the data I needed on lambda. However if I retrieve the html from axios, and try to load that with cheerio, it throws an error.
This is the call im making that doesnt work:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
```

My code is below:

```
"use strict";
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const url = "https://news.ycombinator.com";

const newsHandler = {
    "newsIntent": async function () {
        var speechOutput = "";

        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
                data = [];
                const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
                $("table.itemlist tr td:nth-child(3)").each((i, elem) => {
                    data.push(
                        $(elem).text().trim()
                    );
                });
                for (const headline of data) {
                    speechOutput += headline + " ";
                }
                this.emit(":tell", speechOutput);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
}

module.exports = newsHandler;
```

It should be able to parse through the HTML retrieved from Axios, for all the elements with the described selector, and add their text to the data array.
However even just writing the line:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
```

causes an error. Please help!

Comment: Can you show us what's the `response.data`?

Comment: response.data, when I run it locally is the entire html document as you would find if you went on a webpage's source. But I can't really see what response.data is when I run it on the lamba because I test it via the skill console and I can only make Alexa speak clean text strings so I cant make her say what response.data would be and I'm not sure how I might even be able to see what it is from the lambda

Comment: What does lambda response say? Does it work, but only results from cheerio don't arrive? My best guess, would be that loading a page takes a while, so lambda might be timing out before completing your request. Can you try increasing timeout length?

Comment: Try to do two things:
Use await at the Axios and try to increase the lambda timings.

Answer (score 1):

Check your lambda timeout and try to increase it.

The same happens to me, it was making a **scraper** with node that runs on aws lambda, the problem that I had was that the function ends because of a timeout.

First I was using *JSDOM* and then *cheerio* with both libraries I had the same problem.

The solution was to increase the lambda timeout (mine was only 3 seconds), I increase it to 10 seconds and it works perfectly. After that, I discover that the whole function to **scrape** a single URL was taking about 5 seconds.